# Можно ли изменить длину текстового поля в JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Tags: java

Подскажите, как можно изменить длину текстового поля в JOptionPane.showInputDialog? Поле по умолчанию получается очень длинным, а мне всего нужно вводить 6 символов. Можно ли его сделать короче?
Код диалога:

```
public class JAdvansedOptionPane extends JOptionPane {
public static String showInputDialog(final Object title, final Object message, final Object[] options)
        throws HeadlessException {
    final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null,
            options, null);
    pane.setWantsInput(true);
    pane.setComponentOrientation((getRootFrame()).getComponentOrientation());
    pane.setMessageType(QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    pane.selectInitialValue();
    final JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, title.toString());
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispose();
    final Object value = pane.getInputValue();
    return (value == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) ? null : (String) value;
}
```

}

Вызываю так:

```
String response = JAdvansedOptionPane.showInputDialog("header", "label", new Object[]{"Input", "Close"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Залезаем в JavaDoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html ищем как получить список всех "сыновей/дочерей".
2. За это у нас отвечает метод

   public Component getComponent(int n)
   Gets the nth component in this container.
   Note: This method should be called under AWT tree lock.

   Parameters:
   n - the index of the component to get.
   Returns:
   the nth component in this container.
   Throws:
   ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - if the nth value does not exist.

Перебором устанавливаем объект который нам нужен. TextField :  Здесь он находится под индексом 0.

3. Пробуем поискать среди методов те, что влияют на размер. Сработал этот  :

   setPreferredSize(Dimension preferredSize)
   Sets the preferred size of this component to a constant value.

Но тут есть одно но, не силен в JAWT, но возможно, если установлен какой то менеджер размещения объектов, это может не сработать, или отражаться неправильно

Так же, можно просматривать иерархию в возрастающем порядке вызывая `getParent()`

Ну и, ваш код.

```
public static String showInputDialog(final Object title, final Object message, final Object[] options)
        throws HeadlessException {

    final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            OK_CANCEL_OPTION, null, options, null);
    pane.setWantsInput(true);


    // - >
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 85));
    // - > IF NEED RESIZE MAIN PAIN

    pane.setComponentOrientation((getRootFrame()).getComponentOrientation());
    pane.setMessageType(QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    pane.selectInitialValue();

    // -> resize daughter components
    pane.getComponent(0).setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
    // -> resize daughter components


    JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(pane, title.toString());
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispose();
    final Object value = pane.getInputValue();
    return (value == UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) ? null : (String) value;
}
```